# Unable to create repository on IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm able to login successfully with : ibmcloud cr login

but when i try to create a repository in the registry, i have the following error :

```
docker push registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/fdutreg/ksrepo
The push refers to repository [registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/fdutreg/ksrepo]
428c97da766c: Preparing
unauthorized: The login credentials are not valid, or your IBM Cloud account is not active.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I hope you followed the instructions mentioned here - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Registry/index.html#index

Comment: The <region> was wrong registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net instead registry.eu-de.bluemix.net. Now it is ok. :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net by registry.eu-de.bluemix.net and now this is ok.

Answer (score 2):

2 years later but probably someone could be experimenting the same issue. The thing is that you are not authenticate to the registry. You can authenticate with an API key using:

docker login -u iamapikey -p apikey registry_url

For the apikey field you can create an apikey in Manage > IAM > APIkeys > Create an IBM Cloud API key in ibm.cloud.com

It is important to know that Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin. You can find alternatives in https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Registry?topic=Registry-registry_access

Answer (score 2):

Log your local Docker daemon into the IBM Cloud Container Registry.run the following command:

```
ibmcloud cr login
```